# Which is the best approach for searching the dictionary items?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, comparative-review, search

We can search for the list of dictionaries using the below some approaches, Can one please help me, which one is the memory efficient approach to use?

Provided that:

- `name`s are unique in the list
- There will be definitely a `name` in each dictionary.

Where as:

```
items = [list_of_dicts]
name_to_b_searched = "some_name"
```

## 1 direct return from the for loop

```
def get_by_name(self, name_to_be_searched):
    for i in items:
        if i['name'] == name_to_be_searched:
              return i
```

## 2 Break from the for loop and return found dictionary

```
def get_by_name(self, name_to_be_searched):
    found = None
    for i in items:
        if i['name'] == name_to_be_searched:
              found = i
              break 
    return found
```

## 3 A generator function

```
def get_by_name(self, name_to_be_searched):
    for i in items:
        if i['name'] == name_to_be_searched:
              yield i
```

## 4 An inline generator

```
get_by_name =next(i for i in items if i['name'] == name_to_be_searched, None)
```

Sometimes I could have a huge csv records (in items), so was thinking which approach would be better to search a record.
OR if there is any other approach you would recommend please let me know.

Comment: You did not define *best*.

Comment: @StephenRauch - I did not get you

Comment: You use the word *best*.  This word has no specific technical meaning.

Comment: Sadly, *efficient* is also technically ambiguous.

Comment: Well, you could easily profile each piece of code you have and find out

Comment: CPU efficient or memory efficient?

Comment: @Mast - Memory efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**None of the above**.

> OR if there is any other approach you would recommend please let me
>   know.

The whole point of using dictionaries is that you *don't* need to search anything and can access everything in `O(1)` (on average) instead of the `O(n)` in all of your suggestions.

> - names are unique in the list
> - There will be definitely a name in each dictionary.

So, instead of using a list of dictionaries, use a dictionary of dictionaries using the name as the outer key.

Instead of

```
items = [{'name': 'a', 'age': 22, ...},
         {'name': 'b', 'age': 30, ...}]
```

you should have

```
items = {'a': {'age': 22, ...},
         'b': {'age': 30, ...}}
```

Now you can access each dictionary directly by using the name.

```
name = 'b'
print(items[name]['age'])
#  30
```

No loops, no searches, `O(1)` access.

Comment: I agree. However could you show how you could get such a dictionary?

Comment: @Peilonrayz `dict_of_dicts = {d['name']: d for d in list_of_dictionaries}` Sacrificing a single `O(n)` iteration for many `O(1)` lookups in the future.

Comment: thanks, however I was meaning more to add it to your answer, :)

Comment: OP is worried about memory and you recommend to use faster lookup by doubling the amount of used memory?